# error "secondViewController does not have a member named "mastername"

Tags: swift, tableview, segue

I am using a sample from IOS 8 App Development Essentials. I added a variable to my second controller but keep getting this error.
Second controller code:

```
Class SocondDetailController: UIViewController{
   var mastername: String?
...
}
```

First controller code:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue,sender: AnyObject?) 
{
if segue.identifier == "ShowDetails"
{        
   let detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as SocondDetailController
   let myIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
   let row = myIndexPath?.row 
   SocondDetailController.mastername = tableData[row!]
}
}
```

I am new to Swift and IOS development. Just starting at age 71.
I have been using VB.Net for a long time.

Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This row:

```
SocondDetailController.mastername = tableData[row!]
```

should be:

```
detailViewController.mastername = tableData[row!]
```

`mastername` is an instance property, and as such you have to access to it through an instance of `SocondDetailController`, and not the `SocondDetailController` type itself.

Also, although probably not needed due to the logic in your view controller, I'd avoid using the forced unwrapping operator `!`, preferring a safer optional binding:

```
let row = myIndexPath?.row
if let row = row {
    detailViewController.mastername = tableData[row]    
}
```

or, more concisely:

```
if let row = myIndexPath?.row {
    detailViewController.mastername = tableData[row]    
}
```

Comment: I replaced the SecondDetailController with detailViewController as you suggested. Now the error is "anyObject is not convertible to String"

Comment: I presume that `tableData` is defined as an array of `AnyObject` - is that correct?

Comment: I should have indicated that I am trying to pass the text from one cell of the first tableView to the second one. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are correct. It is from JSON data that was converted.

Comment: Ok. But without looking at the relevant code it's not easy to provide a proper answer, besides suggesting to apply a downcast `tableData[row] as? String` - that might solve the problem, if not I suggest creating a new question, as it is a different problem

Comment: Getting closer. The tableData array is an array containing two labels. Can I select the value using the array index of the row selected?

Comment: Hard to say... if by label you mean string, and if that array is used to populate the rows, and the index of each array element corresponds to the row number, then yes.